# initializing angular after DOM has changed, doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to re-initialize my angular app, so it will re-render the DOM since I injected  elements after loading.
This is the short version of my angular function:

**JS**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.highlighter1 = function(side, string, load) {
              highlighter.deserialize(string);
};

$http.get('/comments')
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.comments = response;
    var allEl=[];
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
        allEl.push(response[i]._id);
    }
    $http.post('/ranges', {"commentIds":allEl})
    .success(function(result){
        result.forEach(function(item){
            $scope.highlighter1(item.dataAction, item.rangyObject, true); 
      })
    })
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementsByTagName('span'),['myApp']);
})
})(window.angular);
```

my 's are injected when I run the deserializing of the highlighter object. I'm also assigning them attributes of uib-popover, so in the end I have 's in my documents with these attributes, and I'm re-rendering them when calling on angular.bootstrap again on them.

They are being rendered (when I try to manually call it again from the console it says that it fails because these elements are already rendered), but the pop-over still doesn't do what it's supposed to do (when I click it doesn't popover).

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300);

body {
  color: #595959;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


.highlight-a {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #99c2ff;
 border: 1px solid #7699d1;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #223f7a;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in comments">
    <div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId={{i._id}}> {{i.text}}     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your markup

Comment: I re-edited the question and provided the relevant parts of the markup

Comment: oops, sorry, i meant the html

Comment: btw, the popover can be readily seen in the DOM when it is active. It adds the popover element. I don't see any elements in the DOM, so it looks like it's not activated at all, and it's not just the fact that I can't see it. Also, I didn't tailor a mark-up for it but just use the native one from uib-popover .

Comment: `I'm trying to re-initialize my angular app, so it will re-render the DOM since I injected elements after loading. ` why are you doing this ?

Comment: Because the <span>'s (that were injected) weren't rendered with the angular app, I assumed the uib-popover property that I injected them with won't work.